# Apple Calendar does not show private items from Exchange delegations

Tags: calendar, exchange

I've added my Exchange calendar to the Apple Calendar app. Now I've opened the calendar of my colleague (as delegation) but I can't see items that he marked as private. Outlook shows private items with a generic title like "private appointment", but Apple Calendar doesn't.

Is there any way to make this work?